# ovirt engine and host setup issue

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I am using 2 computers and both are running fedora 23. In computer A I have installed ovirt engine 4.0 and in computer B I installed ovirt node 4.0.3 on a virtual machine manager and both the computer are in a same network.

When I login to the engine admin account using web interface, I tried to setup a host, but always gives error as install failed as shown below, any idea whats going wrong here?

[Engine Host setup error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YSoZ.png)

I thought it might be due to node storage issue, I tried to setup a node shared storage, again it gives error. Can anyone help how to setup a shared storage for node?

[Node storage setup issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dwOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

in the lower panel you can see a message telling you that it failed to verify power management configuration. 
You can see more messages if you'll go to the events tab.
For full details you can check the host installation log.

Comment: power management configuration is not mandatory as per one of the tutorial as i am installing a test server. I viewed events tab `"Host oVirtHost installation failed. Command returned failure code 1 during SSH session 'root@192.168.1.122'."`. I also checked engine log and following output were given [Log 1](https://i.imgsafe.org/d78c3c9cd4.png) [Log 2](https://i.imgsafe.org/d78d3d0dc0.png). any idea of this error?

Comment: The tab should tell you where the installation log file is located. The engine log just indicates installation failed, but to understand why we need the installation log file. Please check in the event and check the installation log file for more details.